# How to handle mandatory fields in a web page/form (When we skip any mandatory field during form fillup.)

Tags: javascript

How to handle following scenario in a generic way...I am looking to implement the following things for multiple web pages.(So, please help me out BY SUGGESTING ANY GENERIC way).

Scenario:

1. If a webpage/form has a 4 mandatory fields(text box).
2. If i select 2nd field by skipping the first one
3. Then, first mandatory field text box should be shown with red border.

Comment: just put `required` in the input tag meaning the form cant be sent unless all fields have user input

Comment: @Dennington-bear — That does not have the effect requested in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has failed to even try to do this themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the focus event fires on any form control, loop over all the form controls (`this.form.elements` will give you an ordered collection) and run your validation routine on each in turn. Break out of the loop when you reach the currently focused element (i.e. when `this.form.elements[i] === this`).